# Magento not working after move

Tags: magento-1.8, error

In log file i see error:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `atalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1)
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` ON (core_url_rewrite.category_id=e.entity_id) AND (core_url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND core_url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND core_url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('4', '3', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '54', '59', '58', '53', '61', '48', '55', '47', '51', '50', '56', '57', '5', '6', '49', '60', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86')) AND (`e`.`entity_id` NOT IN('5', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '60', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1')
```

but i not know what this error? in another server magento working, after move, not working, how i can solve this problem?

Comment: There should be more errors than that. What does the site do?

Comment: magento 1.8.1 after move in other server not loading, in log file have error, yes right, but when i return files and database in old server, magento working good

Comment: The SQL seems to be around the categories, perhaps set the flat tables to not be used in the `core_config` table, and run a full reindex from shell: `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: A SQL query is not an error. If there is an error related to that query, the error message is in front of it. But this can also be someone's debug statement. Secondly, you should better define "site is not working", to get help. Take a screenshot or describe what goes wrong. There's a huge difference between a blank page and a Magento error page, so try to be very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great, via shel: php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall –  all good

Very Thanks